# Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.9.RELEASE

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am tried to upgrade the app spring boot version to 2.4.9.RELEASE, but when I compile the app code, shows error like this:

```
> Configure project :dolphin-acientbay
/home/runner/work/retire/retire
> Configure project :dolphin-post
/home/runner/work/retire/retire
> Configure project :dolphin-template
/home/runner/work/retire/retire
> Task :dolphin-common:generateLombokConfig

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

> Task :dolphin-common:compileJava FAILED
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':dolphin-common:compileJava'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':dolphin-common:compileClasspath'.
2 actionable tasks: 2 executed
   > Could not find org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-parent:2.4.9.RELEASE.
     Required by:
         project :dolphin-common

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 47s
Error: Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I found the repo contains the jar file: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.4.9/. what should I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1):

tweak the spring boot gradle plugin to:

```
id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.4.9"
```

and remove the `RELEASE` of the version no, only keep the number version.